# Subscribe ROS Image and CameraInfo sensor.msgs format

Tags: image, python-2.7, publish-subscribe, ros

I am trying to subscribe to CameraInfo and Image of format sensor_msgs.msg and use its data for further image processing. Here are few lines of code that I am starting with:

```
from sensor_msgs.msg import CameraInfo, Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('node_name')
    while ~rospy.is_shutdown():
        sub_cam_info = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/rgb/raw_camera_info', CameraInfo)
        sub_rgb = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/rgb/raw_image_color', Image)
```

From here I want to extract header and data information from 'sub_cam_info' and 'sub_rgb'. Something like this:

```
camera_info_K = sub_cam_info.K
camera_info_dist_model = sub_cam_info.distortion_model
rgb_image = CvBridge().imgmsg_to_cv2(sub_rgb, encoding="rgb8")
```

And then use this data for image undistortion:-

```
rgb_undist = cv2.undistort(rgb_img.data, camera_info_K, camera_info_dist_model)
```

Mainly I need help in second part, i.e., extraction of parameters from CameraInfo and Image messages. However, if someone can help me to sort out body of this whole code! I am already through making up my own CameraInfo and RGB messages, using them for undistortion and publishing on ROS by, but now I want to get them from another ROS module and work with them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok for newbies like me I solved it like this:

```
import message_filters
import cv2
import rospy
from cv_bridge import CvBridge

def callback(rgb_msg, camera_info):
   rgb_image = CvBridge().imgmsg_to_cv2(rgb_msg, desired_encoding="rgb8")
   camera_info_K = np.array(camera_info.K).reshape([3, 3])
   camera_info_D = np.array(camera_info.D)
   rgb_undist = cv2.undistort(rgb_image, camera_info_K, camera_info_D)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   rospy.init_node('my_node', anonymous=True)
   image_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/ardrone/front/image_raw', Image)
   info_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/ardrone/front/camera_info', CameraInfo)
   ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([image_sub, info_sub], 10, 0.2)
   ts.registerCallback(callback)
   rospy.spin()
```

So my problem was how to subscribe on two different topics and use their data for further processing. "message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer" synchronized the incoming messages according to the time stamp with each message being received and with "ts.registerCallback(callback)" i was able to use both subscribed messages together for further processing in callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you get the `sub_rgb` image by using `cv2.imshow()`?

And printed out the camera configuration to check if it was obtained successfully?

You need to run the camera launch file and then initiate the `node_name`

After doing this if you get error let me know.

I wrote a code to get ROS image and convert it to Mat (OpenCV format)